# Rspec integration tests without cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, webrat

Is there a way to do integration tests with Rspec without using Cucumber? I prefer using just plain old Webrat. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The latest version of [RSpec-Rails](http://rspec.info/) (1.2.7) now has integration support. Upgrade then start adding specs to spec/integration or use the 'integration_spec' generator. Configure Webrat in spec/spec_helper.rb and you're set!

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why they incorporated integration specs to rspec, given the popularity of cucumber.

Comment: There's many places where Cucumber would be overkill, like testing internal APIs, for example.

Answer (score 6):

We've recently started using RSpec with Capybara over Cucumber. Here is a "beginners" blog post I recently wrote on using RSpec integration tests without cucumber.

[End-to-end testing with RSpec integration tests and Capybara](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/33771089985/rspec-integration-tests-with-capybara)

Let me know if you have any questions on getting your system set up.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Rspec is perfectly capable of testing views and controllers as part of integration tests. A quick look around the internet shows [this article at Robby on Rails on view testing](http://www.robbyonrails.com/articles/2007/08/02/spec-your-views) and some of the [Rdocs within RSpec](http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec-rails/1.2.6/classes/Spec/Rails/Example/ViewExampleGroup.html) might help.

Hope this points you in the right direction - I'm afraid I use cucumber myself.